# WHM and cPanel database and settings storing place

Tags: cpanel, whm

I'm trying to figure out where all WHM settings are stored. I got a task to prepare some template with WHM and cPanel installed but I can't find anywhere any information what is the name of the database where information (with settings) are stored.

I'm precisely looking for the option to turn on email notification in cPHulk about banned user IPs. I know that I can set it up later but I don't want to make any of initial setup in WHM/cPanel.

Is any chance to manually change this settings value ? (either in database or file).

I'm looking as well where are stored values for WHM option: "Show IP Address Usage"

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can only preconfigure WHM using cpanel.config file as described in their docs: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1144Docs/The+cpanel.config+File

Unfortunately, this only covers 'Tweak Settings' section, so you can't preconfigure cPHulk using it. One of the alternatives would be to use WHM API and fire it after the server is installed. With this API you have way more options, e.g. cPHulk controls are there: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/WHM+API+1+Functions+-+load_cphulk_config